# Inner join with Cursors resulting another Cursor object

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, android-contentprovider

In fact I have 2 `Cursor`s one is SQLite cursor, another one comes from `ContentProvider` - beneath it lies complicated SQLite query - but I don't have access to it.

Both cursors has the same unique `_ID` field. In a pure SQL it would be really easy to join them using those id field, but not in my case, since 2nd Cursor is not SQLite query.

I need to produce resulting joined `Cursor`. Neither `CursorJoiner` nor `MergeCursor` doesn't help me.

Any ideas, clues, hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option #1: Write your own implementation of `Cursor` -- perhaps extending `AbstractCursor` -- that does the join. I have some ancient code in [an obsolete version of a discontinued book](http://commonsware.com/AdvAndroid/AdvAndroid-1_2-CC.pdf) that demonstrates this (see pages 186-190).

Option #2: Create a `MatrixCursor` that represents the join.

Comment: Thanks for hint and sources, I've solved my task using `AbstractCursor`

Comment: Hi @barmaley, is it possible for you just to share some insights concerning to this?

Comment: Sure, @karate: what d'u want to know?

Comment: @barmaley No need anymore, tried to implement AbstractCursor for LeftJoin. Thanks for the post and for the answers.