# How to JOIN 2 Android cursors into one?

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, inner-join

Is that possible to combine the results of 2 `Cursors` by using `INNER JOIN` approach (merge horizontally) and as a result have only one Cursor? I know CursorJoiner class, but couldn't understand how to combine the results into one `Cursor` with this.

EDIT:

Just as an information for the people who would need to do something like this. From my side I have tried to implement AbstractCursor. I have found this [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14280842/inner-join-with-cursors-resulting-another-cursor-object) which is similar question answered by @CommonsWare.
I don't have enough rights, but someone else could mark the question as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

The cursor will store the query data,if you need something like an Inner Join, do it when create the query, then the cursor will have the result you want.

This question have an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957009/how-do-i-join-two-sqlite-tables-in-my-android-application) with rawQuery.

Comment: In this case, I need the Cursor way for 2 reasons:
1. Join query is not possible to execute on different databases without attach. In my case the second database comes from completely different application.
2. To not refactor a lot of code

Anyway AbstractCursor implementation solved my problem, but it is time consuming to implement by considering every possible aspect concerning to join columns.

Comment: this [link](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.database.MergeCursor)  have some examples

Comment: The purpose of MergeCursor is different, it appends the result rows from different tables vertically, but not horizontally. It is not a JOIN. Please read the post which I have mentioned in the question. The link is now included.

Comment: ah, got it, you need to merge the columns to existing register in the first cursor right ? if is the case, i think is better implement that outside the cursors, because can happen to cursors return the results in different positions, so you will need to check if the register of Cursor A is the same of the Cursor B,  maybe create an object to store the data from all cursors and group then in a List is an easy approach

Comment: Exactly. But that would be one time usage, where the MatrixCursor is fine.